# busca_binaria em python

Tags: python, lista, binary

Preciso criar uma função de busca binária. A função deve procurar o alvo na lista.
verifica se lista[meio] é o numero que quero.Se for, retorna True.
Se nao for, e o meio for maior, entao pode pegar um novo fim: meio-1
Se nao for, e o meio for menor, entao pode pegar um novo começo.
Segue o código que estou tentando:

```
def busca_binaria(lista, alvo):
    ini = 0
    fim = len(lista)-1
    meio = (ini + fim)//2
    if alvo in lista:
        while alvo != lista[meio]:
            if lista[meio] > alvo:
                fim = meio-1
            else:
                ini = meio-1
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Não sei pq não esta funcionando...não retorna...

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98464/discussion-on-question-by-tatiane-berrocal-busca-binaria-em-python)

Answer (score 2):

Vamos por partes...

Primeiro, se o seu objetivo é apenas retornar `True` se o elemento for encontrado, 
você não deveria estar usando o teste:

`if alvo in lista:`  no seu código: esse é o jeito
normal do Python de procurar elementos em listas, e ele
já faz a busca retornando verdadeiro ou falso - e faz
isso usando um algoritmo linear (embora faça isso 
"internamente", dentro do próprio runtime do Python). 
Daí nem adianta você fazer uma busca binária, por que já
fez a operação mais lenta só pra começar sua busca binária - 
não adianta executar a busca rápida depois disso: só vai aumentar
o tempo.  E também, como você só retorna True ou False, e o Python
já indicou que o elemento existe na lista, a busca perde o sentido:
já sabemos a reposta antes dela começar.

Agora, o maior erro no código que você está tentando
é que você só atualiza o `meio` *fora* da busca.
Você atualiza o incio e o fim, ok, mas, não sei se você
tem o costume de usar Excel, onde os valores das células com
fórmulas são re-calculados automaticamente quando os valores
de entrada usam, mas em programação imperativa - o estilo
mais usado em programação com linguagens, inclsive em Python,
isso não funciona assim - o valor de "meio" só é computado 
quando a linha

```
meio = (ini + fim)//2
```

for executada - e isso só acontece antes de o programa entrar no 
seu laço `while`.

Por conta de você fazer a verificação de existência "por fora", 
naquele `if alvo in lista`, a lógica do seu while até está certa,
quase que por coincidência, afinal ou o elemento é encontrado,
ou é encontrado (sim ou sim :-) ) - e você nunca term que retornar
um False depois que entrou no while. O que falha mesmo é que como
o valor de "meio" nunca é atualizado, o programa vai ficar parado 
comparando o mesmo valor (e descobrindo que é falso) toda vez --
usando 100% de CPU e nunca encerrando a função.

Uma coisa que fica quase um detalhe aí, mas que é importante para você
entender: embora o uso do `else` para o `while` não seja um erro de sintaxe
em Python, ele é raramente usado - no caso ele só indica
que o `while` foi terminado sem ser por um comando "break". 
Você poderia só retornar `True` ali sem o bloco de `else`, já
que ele só sai do `while` quando achar o elemento buscado.

E por fim, nesse tipo de algoritmo, um ponto comum de erros é justamente 
escolher os pontos de início, fim e meio sem "errar por um" ao tentar
fazer os ajustes de "comprimento - 1", e etc.. . A linguagem Python
simplifica isso ao escolher, de forma elegante, que sempre que você
pensa em sequências, o índice "final" indica onde a busca *para* - você
não olha o elemento naquele índice. (então num vetor de comprimento "9", 
a busca é feita nos elementos nas posições de 0 até 8, naturalmente - 
o "meio" é "(0 + 9) // 2" => int(4.5) => 4". E tudo bem 
somar usar "meio -1 " e "meio + 1" para escolher os novos 
inicio  fim. Perceba que justamente se "inicio == fim" e você
*não* encontrou o número, quer dizer que o elemento não está na lista - 
nesse caso você retorna "False" (e nao precisa do "if elemento in lista").

**resumindo**:
De tudo o acima, o mais importante é que o cálculo do `meio` precisa ficar dentro do `while` .  Leia com atenção o restante para melhorar a coisa toda, mas entenda essa parte primeiro.

(em tempo - por questões obvias, não vou dar a resposta pronta - fique a vontade para entender o que está acima, refazer o seu código, e postar mais perguntas se for necessário)

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, o algoritmo de busca binária só funciona satisfatoriamente se a lista estiver **ordenada**. Em segundo lugar, percebi que você está tentando implementar um algoritmo de **busca binária iterativa**.

Pois bem, para implementarmos o algoritmo de **busca binária iterativa** devemos:

1. Indicar a lista ordenada;
2. Identificar o alvo;
3. Identificar o início, tamanho e fim da lista;
4. Criar uma fórmula para calcular o meio;
5. Realizar as iterações pertinentes.
6. Exibir o resultado.

Com esta lógica podemos implementar o seguinte código:

```
def busca_binaria_iterativa(lis, alv):
    ini = 0
    tam = len(lis)
    fim = tam - 1
    while ini <= fim:
        meio = ((ini + fim) // 2)
        if alv < lis[meio]:
            fim = meio - 1
        elif alv > lis[meio]:
            ini = meio + 1
        else:
            return True
    return False


lista = sorted(map(int, input('Digite os valores: ').split()))
alvo = int(input('Digite o valor a ser procurado: '))

print(busca_binaria_iterativa(lista, alvo))
```

Observe que quando executamos este código, recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite os valores:` . Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores da lista, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `Enter`.

Tendo digitado todos os valores, os mesmos serão montados em uma lista, em ordem crescente. Em seguida, devemos digitar o valor a ser pesquisado e pressionar `Enter`. Depois destas operações a lista é passada como parâmetro para a função `busca_binaria_iterativa()`.

Uma vez, o fluxo do programa chegando à referida função, serão definidas as seguintes variáveis: **ini = 0**, **tam = len(lis)** e **fim = tam - 1**.

A partir deste momento é iniciado a execução do bloco de repetição **while**. Então, neste momento, será verificado se **ini <= fim**. Caso positivo, será calculado o `meio`, através da fórmula: **meio = ((ini + fim) // 2)**.

**Observação 1**

O `meio` deve ser implementado dentro do bloco while. Pois, esta variável será atualizada à cada iteração do while.

**Observação 2**

Para fins de eficiência e exatidão, no cálculo do `meio` utilizamos uma divisão inteira - "**//**" - e não uma divisão real - "**/**".

Após ter sido calculado o `meio` o fluxo do código entrará no bloco de decisões. Neste momento se **alv < lis[meio]**, a variável `fim` será atualizada para o valor de `meio - 1` e o bloco while será novamente executado. Caso **alv > lis[meio]**, a variável `ini` será atualizada para o valor de `meio + 1` e o bloco while será novamente executado. Caso contrário, ou seja, **alv == lis[meio]** a função encerra sua execução retornando o valor **True**.

Agora, depois de ter realizado todas as iterações e o valor `alv` não for encontrado, a função encerra sua execução retornando o valor **False**.

**Testando o código**

Imagine que a nossa lista seja [12, 15, 22, 37, 46, 51, 68, 73] e que desejamos pesquisar por um determinado valor. Então, executamos o código e, no momento que recebermos a mensagem: `Digite os valores:` , devemos digitar...

```
12 15 22 37 46 51 68 73
```

...e pressionar `enter`.

Em seguida devemos digitar o valor a ser pesquisado. Suponhamos que desejamos pesquisar pelo valor **37**. Então, no momento que recebermos a mensagem: `Digite o valor a ser procurado:` , devemos digita...

```
37
```

...e pressionar `enter`.

A partir deste momento o código realizará todo o trabalho de pesquisa e nos retornará:

```
True
```

O retorno da função foi `True` porque, de fato, o valor **37** pertence à lista.

Agora, se o valor procurado **não pertence** à lista, o retorno da função será **False**.